# How to get resize acitivity perfomed by kendo Splitter in angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, resize, mutation

I am using [Mutation observer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mutationobserver-example-tmafmw) to detect dom resize event done by Kendo Splitter to an angular componen, when I resize the whole browser window or manually change the style in developer's tool in chrome, the mutation is working, but if kendo splitter is resizing the dom, the mutation observer is not getting triggered at all.

Here is the parent splitter

```
  <kendo-splitter>
        <kendo-splitter-pane [resizable]="true" size="50%">
          <div class="a-card">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="a-body">
                <product-list></product-list>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </kendo-splitter-pane>
        <kendo-splitter-pane size="50%">
          <product-details></product-details>
        </kendo-splitter-pane>
      </kendo-splitter>
```

Inside Product-list angular component, I am using this [Mutation Observer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mutationobserver-example-tmafmw) to get the resize event, but when I resize the kendo splitter, the mutation observer is not getting triggered. 
But I can clearly see in computed properties of developer's tool in chrome that interested element's style has been changed.

Do I have to change anything in mutation observer code?

Comment: Can you please replicate it somewhere, e.g. at stackblitz?

Comment: yes m trying to do it now